# SessionID for FetchToken ebay

Tags: ebay-api

I'm trying to get the ebay GetSessionID and FetchToken functions to work - I've set up the credentials for my application ok, so I have DeveloperID, ApplicationID, CertificateID and RuName - when I call GetSessionID, ebay generates a sessionid for me, I then call eBay's consent form, where I log in to a sandbox user account, and ebay redirects me back to my web application.

The problem is that when I call the FetchToken function, passing the SessionID returned to me previously, I get the following error message

"Your session ID is for ID verification, not for FetchToken, please use correct RuName when making GetSessionID call"

I can't find an explanation of this error anywhere online. My understanding of ebay is that after signing into the consent form, ebay should return to my application with a token which I can then use to query that users ebay data. The error I'm getting would seem to suggest that different sessionid's are used for different things

Any idea's where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer - in case anyone is having a similar problem.

If you go to your ebay developer account, click application settings, then after selecting your environment and keyset (Sandbox and Keyset1 in my case), it will show a section named "Manage your RuNames".

Assuming you've already set up an RuName, there will be a dropdown listbox named "Token Return Method", which needs to be set to "Authorization" to return a token that represents an ebay users permission for you to query their account. The other setting is "ID Verification", which will result in the error message shown in the question above if you try to call the FetchToken function in the ebay API.

Once again, simple & obvious when you know how - the problem is trawling through the 1000's of pages of forums, documentation etc to find it. Ebay doesn't make this easy because there is too much legacy documentation online - make sure you look at the latest version!

Comment: Its funny, I just found this question and was about to give you this answer. Good work on finding it.

Answer (score 0):

**RuName (eBay Redirect URL name)**

*Users Tokens* -> *Get a Token from eBay via Your Application*

[image]